# detecting certain character chunks

Tags: c

`inputData[] = {Zw~~"}`;

why doesn't this code work?

```
if (inputData[ii] == '~' && inputData[ii + 1] == '~')
```

I want to detect the ~~ some how

```
void readInputDataForDecryption(void)
{
  int i, ii;
  ii = 0;
  int counter = 0;

  for (i = startIndexForData; i < characterCounter; i++, ii++)

  { 

    counter++;
    inputData[ii] = inputLine[i];

    if (inputData[ii] == '~' && inputData[ii + 1] == '~')
    {
      printf("ii: %d\n", ii);
      printf("found ~~\n");
    }
    dataCharCount++;
  } 

}
```

Comment: it seems you're missing some code at the beginning

Comment: this is just a chunk of code taken out of my program

Comment: not your answer, but counter and ii seem to keep the exact same value during the whole function... why this redundancy? Also watch out when accessing inputData[ii+1], this will work because '\0' will keep you safe, but if you were to use inputData[ii+2], you're reading out of bounds.

Comment: Think that you are at very last index, then `inputData[ii+1]` leads to a segmentation fault.

Comment: @Ptival, how do you know it's null-terminated? That's not indicated anywhere in the source I can see.

Comment: @Ken haha, I sure hoped so, but you're right, it's not even sure! At least he gets the idea: be sure of your indices if you really want to access ahead...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't work because you're trying to read data from somewhere you haven't put data yet.

```
inputData[ii] = inputLine[i];  // You've initialized inputData[ii]

if (inputData[ii] == '~' && inputData[ii + 1] == '~') // nothing in inputData[ii + 1] yet.
```

Reverse your check (and don't check until ii is at least in the second iteration):

```
if (inputData[ii] == '~' && inputData[ii - 1] == '~') // Note change from + to -
```

Answer (score 0):

- I do not see `startIndexForData` initialized anywhere.
- I do not see `chracterCounter` initialized anywhere.
- You refer to both `inputData` and `inputLine`, but haven't defined either one.
- You refer to `dataCharCount`, but don't show us anything about it.
- `counter` is initialized, and incremented, but never used.  What is that?

Given all these problems, its pretty hard to properly analyze your code.
Maybe that alone is the root cause of the problem?

Comment: This is not an answer. It's a comment.

Comment: @Ken: I disagree.  I pointed out multiple possible causes of the problem, especially since he said the code doesn't work, without describing how it fails, and what he expects certain key variables to be.   If he fixes the problems I describe, he'll likely have working code, ergo, it is a solution.

Comment: It's pretty obvious that those variables are global, since they're not declared in the function. The extraneous `counter` increment definitely doesn't, yet you mention it. None of the things you indicate have anything to do with the code posted (as far as you can see, anyway), and you've provided no information that would help resolve it. How is that an answer?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to change

```
for (i = startIndexForData; i < characterCounter; i++, ii++)
```

to

```
for (i = ii = startIndexForData; i < characterCounter; i++, ii++)
```

Apart from that, as abelenky has mentioned, your code is not very complete - which might be one source of the problem or not (depending how much you have left out prior to posting)